# EXCEPT command - Find sailors who’ve reserved all boats

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division, not-exists, sql-except

I am reading a textbook and I do not understand this query: 
Find sailors who’ve reserved all boats.

- We have 3 tables:

  1. Sailors: sid, sname, rating, age  (primary: sid)
  2. Boats:   bid (primary: bid)
  3. Reserves: sid, bid, day (primary, sid, bid, day) (sid is foreign key to sailors, bid is foreign key to boats)

For the query, Find sailors who’ve reserved all boats, the answer given is:

```
SELECT  S.sname
FROM  Sailors S
WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
          ((SELECT  B.bid
             FROM  Boats B)
            EXCEPT
             (SELECT  R.bid
              FROM  Reserves R
              WHERE  R.sid=S.sid))
```

My questions are:

1. Is there something wrong with the above query? When I put it into MySQL Workbench, it shows I have syntax error with the EXCEPT
2. Beside the solution given by the book above, is there any other way to do the query: Find sailors who’ve reserved all boats

Thank you,

Comment: `except` is not valid in MySQL. You can use it in SQL Server.

Comment: You can rewrite the `except` into `NOT EXISTS()`

Comment: And you could even rewrite it into `NOT IN()` : http://stackoverflow.com/q/26697519/905902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using COUNT and CONCAT. This query selects the sailors that are paired (in the Reserves table) with each boat in the boat table:

```
SELECT Sailors.name
FROM Sailors INNER JOIN
(SELECT Reserves.sid
 FROM Reserves
 GROUP BY Reserves.sid
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(Reserves.sid, Reserves.bid)) =
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Boats.bid)
  FROM Boats)) sub
ON Sailors.sid = sub.sid
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82005/2

Answer (score 3):

Sometime i have seen that `EXCEPT` don't work due to incompatibility with the installed version of `MySql`. Following is the query which can be used in place of yours using `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT S.sname 
FROM Sailors S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.bid 
                  FROM Boats B
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT R.bid
                                   FROM Reserves R
                                   WHERE R.bid = B.bid
                                         AND R.sid = S.sid));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should be used:

```
SELECT sname FROM Sailors s ,Reserves r WHERE  s.sid=r.sid AND r.bid=ALL(SELECT b.bid FROM boats b);
```

Comment: This would not work. WHERE clauses look at each record individually. This [r.bid=ALL (SELECT b.bid FROM boats b);] is saying this individual r.bid is equal to every b.bid in boats. This is always false for 2 or more unique boats.